# Phone 7 (Mango) background URL polling?

Tags: c#, background, polling, windows-phone-7

Whats the recommended way to poll a URL every 5min (in the background) on a Phone 7 (Mango) device ?

Are Periodic Agents limited to 30min polling ?
Should I be looking into Push Notifications  ?

Any pointers/hints appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yop you should be looking into push notification (it's a lot more complicated than the periodic agent...)

But periodic agent are set to 30 mins (and 25sec of code execution I think) and there is NOTHING you can do about it. Also note that the user can decide to deactivate your periodic agent in the options.

But pushing notifications every 5 minutes on a phone might not be good idea anyway... It's gonna drain the battery quickly!

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Authenticating the phone on LAN/Wifi for Untangle. By sending a URL to untangle every 5 minutes once logged in, you can surf the net without captive portal popping up every 5 min. (Yes we could expand the 5min, but its a school so short kick offs on captive portal are enabled.)

Comment: Haha I see... Well you can have the app "sleeping" in the back and doing the authentication job again when woken up. So you just have to switch to it for a sec.

Comment: Just a little idea: If you are making the app for yourself you might find a debug option to force the Periodic agent to run every 5 mins. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: When you say "sleeping" and being woken up ? Will the push notification wake the sleeping app ? (new to this kind of stuff on phone 7).

Comment: I don't think that a push notification can wake up an app... To make it simple WP7.5 keeps 5 apps sleeping at the most. Meaning that they are not running but kept in memory. So when you don't have to wait for it to resume when you switch on them. have a look at that: http://borntolearn.mslearn.net/wpmango/m/mediagallery/default.aspx?PageIndex=1 Chap 5 & 6 might be useful for you.

Comment: Ho and other idea. I'm really not sure that possible but it could be fun, it would be kind of an hack. I think that the Audio Playback agent can have access to the phone more often and can access the net to download music. Maybe you can use one to send auth request every minute instead of downloading music. But you won't be able to listen to music at the same time :p

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be looking into Push Notifications ?

Short answer, yes.

Push notifications will eliminate the need for your app to continuously poll in the background; not only will this help your notifications reach your users faster (as there's no polling delay) it will also improve the user experience on the device, because the app doesn't have to run in the background (taking up resources) while the user is doing other things.

Comment: But I think that you don't have the choice and have to maintain a server that creates the push notifications.